IC identification - TI 08 ABI
I have a TI chip that I cannot find its part number. Can someone help me to identify its part number? It says "TI 08 ABI". I am currently using TI part marking look up link here: https://www.ti.com/packaging/en/docs/partlookup.tsp?partmarking=ABI
I found TLV2452, but I don't know if this is the right one.



It might be easier to confirm if you post a zoomed-out picture out so we can see what components are connected to the pins.

Added! Some passives around but I don't know if this can be much helpful though

And what the PCB is for for what equipment it came from.

Are you sure it's a TI part? TI tends to use their logo, not just the letters "TI".

@Hearth Texas Instruments ubiquitously uses TI as a marking either on the first or second line for their products. Truthfully, I haven't seen any other manufacturer have TI alone as a marking, likely to avoid association.

@Colin I was thinking of LT, oops.

It's a Texas Instruments TLV2452 op amp. You can confirm this using the Chinese distributor LCSC because they have photos of every part they stock. Here is the one of the TLV2452CDGKR:

As you can see it looks close, but slightly different. Texas Instruments do have variations in their marking style though. If we look at the similar TLV2452IDGKR with the marking ABJ:

The style looks exactly like in your picture. So it's likely the marking style has some variations, maybe because they changed it over time.

Hmm... I wonder why OP's device has the marking of one style over the other  even though marking code is not the same. This suggests it could be a private SKU variant of the former.

@Colin I don't think it's a private SKU. I know that TI uses both marking styles, you can see both variations on other VSSOP-8 devices they make. I think the one without the space between TI and the number is just newer.

This is a Texas Instruments TLV2452CDGK. It is an op amp.

Picture from datasheet of aforementioned device.
I was able to find the device by using Texas Instruments' product search tool with ABI as the product marking. Using that marking lists a specific part number in the datasheet.
